# using import 'dart:html' in flutter - Do I need additional dependencies?

Tags: dart, flutter

I came across a websocket example that I would like to use. However it uses `import 'dart:html';`. When I introduce that in my Flutter project seems like its not being picked up. Do I need to add additional dependencies to the `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`dart:html` can't be used in Flutter.
It is for browser applications only.

`dart:html` also only comes with the regular Dart SDK, not with the Dart SDK shipped with Flutter.

Comment: What is the alternative to use HTML/XSLT/XPath features in a Flutter app? Should we use the webview_flutter package?

Comment: I don't know about XSLT/XPath. Does Chrome still support that? I thought that was removed a while ago already.

Comment: Dart SDK for Flutter-WEB do include `dart:html` AFAIK

Comment: That might have changed recently with the introduction of Flutter for the web https://flutter.dev/web

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but let me drop this answer here.

I've searched for a web crawler/scraper for Flutter for a while now. I've tried to use FlutterWebview and also the HTML package but no way. Recently I've found a new package for this.

The advantage of this package is that it is really cross platform as explained:

> Cross-platform dart:html that works in the browser, Dart VM, and Flutter.
>
> - Typical use cases are:
> - Cross-platform application development (e.g. Flutter mobile and web versions).
>   Web crawling and scraping

you can use [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) for any scraping/crawling purpose

Answer (score 3):

Since the merge of Flutter-web into the main Flutter repository, it's no longer possible to directly add imports for web libraries (e.g. dart:html) in a Flutter project on the main channel when targeting Web, Android and iOS.

Use the universal html package which provides extensive support for multiple platforms and web libraries.

From the root level of your project, command

1.
flutter pub add universal_html
2.     import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html

This package isn't required to run some web files (e.g. dart:js). In my case, I just had to remove the import 'dart:js' import statement.