# Visual Studio Code: dart not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I just started working with Flutter, and can run my Flutter apps in Android Studio.  I want to try Visual Studio Code, but when I click my run button, I get this in my Output window:

```
[Running] dart 
"c:\MyStuff\Source\Flutter\hello_world\test\widget_test.dart"
'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.199 seconds
```

My first thought was my Path environment variable, which I have mangled trying to get this to work.  It looks like this:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; c:\Flutter\bin; 
c:\temp\flutter; c:\windows\system32; 
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; 
C:\temp\Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk.old1\bin
```

My c:\temp\Flutter directory looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/584fj.jpg

(I include that because I am a bit lost, and hoping someone will spot something I've done wrong.)

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?  This seems like it should just be basic setup, but I have obviously screwed it up. :(

EDIT:

Thanks for the response!  I actually did that first thing.  Flutter doctor gives me this:

```
[flutter] flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
10.0.16299.547], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
28.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter 
doctor --android-licenses
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.25.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
exit code 0
```

I don't know how to run Flutter doctor with a parameter (-v) in VSCode's command palette.  Maybe that would give me more information.  It seems to allow me only "canned" commands there.  Do you know how I can run Flutter doctor with the -v parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, just place the sdk in an easy to reach place. mine is in the compressed directory of my downloads folder, works best for me this way. After extracting it locate the `flutter_console.bat` file according to your screenshot it is right there in the directory shown by screenshot. Run the file.
Then go to environment variables in User variables modify path, and remove the other flutter directories and that dart directory you have put. put the whole path of the flutter directory for example mine is `C: Users/UserName/Downloads/Compressed/flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta/flutter/bin`
restart computer for the path to be updated

After restart Go to vs code settings in the User Settings, add this line to it

```
"dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Downloads\\Compressed\\flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta\\flutter\\bin",
```

*note the backslashes in above*
This is pointing the editor to the location of the Sdk. Also go to extensions search or marketplace and install the dart and flutter plugins

Comment: Your environment variables should look like this according to your screenshot   `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; C:/temp/ flutter/bin; c:\windows\system32; 
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; `   this is according to what i gather your flutter sdk location is

Comment: Thank you for that--I wasn't even aware of how to get to user settings.  I have done as you said... here are my user settings:

    {
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
        "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
        "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\temp\\Flutter\\bin"
    }

My path now looks like this:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; c:\temp\flutter; c:\windows\system32;

But I still get the same error... "'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: Sorry about the messy formatting... I am not sure how to fix it on stackoverflow.

Comment: One correction--I saw an error in that Path environment variable... I changed c:\temp\flutter to c:\temp\flutter\bin

It still doesn't seem to know where dart is stored.

Comment: I have a second PC at home that I code on... I am going to go home, wipe everything, and try your instructions verbatim.  Thanks, Kevin.  I appreciate your attempt to help me.

Comment: If you put this path `c:\temp\flutter\bin` in the address bar of the file explorer does it lead to the `bin` folder of flutter. also go to this [link](http://www.gekorm.com/dart-windows) and download the dart installer for windows

Comment: Okay, I did that.  Deleting VSCode was a little more than uninstalling it!  But now I have a new problem... when I hover over the import packages, I get the message:  **[dart] Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'**

To the person that asked above about the path in the address bar... yes, the folder exists and does pop up.

Comment: Also, Flutter doctor runs fine, but doesn't show Visual Studio Code at all.  Skips right over where it should display.  It displays "Android Studio (version 3.1)", but no VSCode.  Then says "No issues found!" at the end.

Comment: Attempted to run the app gives me this:

**Warning! This package referenced a Flutter repository via the .packages file that is
no longer available. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is currently
executing will be used instead.**

Comment: WHOA!  Something worked, but it makes no sense to me.  I started a new project and it prompted me to put code inside dart_code_flutter_create.dart, so I pasted in a "hello world" type program.  I did an F5 and deployed it to my phone, and it worked perfectly.

I thought main.dart was supposed to be our startup program?

In any event, I feel tickled pink.  One minor success... lotta learning to go.  Hard to believe a guy told me 2-3 weeks is all you need to learn this.  He must be a lot smarter than I am.

Comment: The restart button seems to work.

Sorry about all the confusion, guys.  Really appreciate the help, though.

Comment: I spoke too soon... getting this now when I try a hot reload:  **Hot reload received invalid response: {type: Sentinel, kind: Collected, valueAsString: <collected>}**

Comment: Okay guys, I restarted the project and now it's working.  The whole IDE feels a little flaky to me, but my knowledge level is so low it's hard to tell.  Kevin, you gave me great information above that I found useful... unfortunately, I am new to Stack Overflow also, so I'll just ask... should I mark your comment above as the answer?    I found it truly informative and appreciate all the effort you put forth for me.  Thank you. :)

Comment: Marking the first answer i posted as correct works i.e `First of all, just place the sdk in an easy to reach place. mine is in the compressed directory of my downloads folder, works best for me this way.`   Also check out the flutter codelabs, its a great place to start with Flutter

Comment: Thank you, Kevin!  I am working to get my emulator set up now.  Everything is new, but I'll get there.  Really appreciate all your help. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding--my organization had us move offices and I am just now set back up.  It won't let me mark a comment as the answer.  I think it has to be an "Answer."  I'll be happy to do so if you want to copy/paste your comment from above and submit as an answer.  Again, appreciate all the help.

Comment: this question has two answers. mine and another guy's. Scroll up this thread and you will see the original answer i posted

Comment: I found it.  I could have sworn the checkmarks weren't there before, but I marked yours as the answer.  I appreciate the other person responding, but it actually wasn't useful for my issue.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Add the path of your Dart sdk into user/system environment variables.
Lets say my Flutter SDK path is :`E:\Android\flutter\bin`

Now my Dart path will be inside :`E:\Android\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin`

So edit the PATH variable and add the value at the end after a semicolon:
`E:\Android\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin;`

and restart the system and open cmd from windows and just simply run dart.

After restart In VS code go to `New Terminal` and add the terminal as Powershell and run dart command.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the path in your VS Code setting.
In `settings.json` set this up:

```
"dart.flutterSdkPath": "/home/jspw/Android/Sdk/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/"
```

`/home/jspw/Android/Sdk/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/` is my dart-sdk path !

You have to restart the VS Code and Boom! It's working fine !

Answer (score 0):

You might have to configure your editor and install the flutter extension in your VScode (Visual Studio) https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/#vscode

Comment: When I run Flutter doctor outside of VSCode, it says "Flutter extension not installed."

I don't understand that, as I actually have installed the extension.  (I tried to attach a screen shot, but apparently I can't inside a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Your pc has not a Dart SDK, You must install Dart sdk in your computer,the link [https://dart.dev/get-dart](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive)

[1](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive): https://dart.dev/get-dart or download a zip file https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive, after decompressing, take the bin folder path and add it to system varriables environement in the path...

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue from using `import 'dart:html';`

Apparently, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50902105/4116924) explains, `dart:html` only comes with the regular Dart SDK, not with the Dart SDK shipped with Flutter.