# VS Code-'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: dart, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install flutter and run the basic flutter example on visual studio code . I used flutter doctor in the command line and installed all the missing requirements , now i try to run a basic program in flutter ,but in visual studio code output i get the following error

```
 [Running] dart "c:\fluttercode\mobile_test1\lib\main.dart"
'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 64.965 seconds
```

I could find only one question similar to this in stack overflow ,
[Visual Studio Code: dart not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828255/visual-studio-code-dart-not-found/51828591)
they told to change environment variables ,i added  the environment variables (however the name of the environment variables was not mentioned in the answer ) 
I checked the dart site in case they mentioned it ,but i couldn't find anything related to the name of the environment variable 
This is what i got from dart site

Windows:
In Windows, setting your PATH and environment variables can be done by opening Control Panel and typing “Environment” and then clicking the “Edit the system environment variables” option. You’ll be presented with a list of environment variables including PATH where you can edit or add new ones.

Note: You should reboot your computer after making changes to PATH to ensure all processes (including explorer) are updated.

So i just  did a guess and added an environment variable with the name FLUTTER_ROOT(cause i remember reading somewhere in one of the settings in VS Code for dart ,this name was used) and pointed it to my flutter bin directory

I restarted my PC and opened vs code and changed in VS Settings >user settings>dart and flutter>Dart:Env   and updated my path

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\src\\flutter\\bin"
}
```

But i get the same error

this is how my flutter  bin folder looks like

[image]

Environment variables in PATH after installing Dart

[image]

Comment: what is your `PATH` env variable after reboot? does it really contain the folder where `dart.exe` is installed?

Comment: I checked the PATH variable ,it didnt have the flutter path in it ,so i added C:\src\futter\bin to the PATH ,and restarted the PC .However this path does not have dart.exe .

Comment: I installed dart on VSCode ,and before installing flutter files i did see a message saying dart is not required if you are building only mobile apps through flutter.But i just now installed dart through Chocolatey and trying to work things out

Comment: I added an image showing the folder structure in my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code: dart not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828255/visual-studio-code-dart-not-found)

Comment: why dont you simply follow the official way: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows?

Comment: @pskink I followed all the steps in the link you sent ,ran flutter doctor each time and corrected everything required .It is only when i am Running the sample app i face this problem

Comment: what is the output of `flutter --version`? does `flutter run lib/main.dart` work?

Comment: Flutter 1.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (3 months ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

Comment: so it found your dart installation - it is 2.1.2 - does `flutter run lib/main.dart` work?

Comment: @pskink  ,Hi the error which i got is resolved , after installing dart and adding path variable and then restarting the PC( i didnt restart PC after installing dart)  .I get a different error now , but thanks for taking your time and helping me out

Comment: what different error?

Comment: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to install the dart SDK if you already have the flutter SDK installed. When you specify the path of flutter, VSCode only recognizes the flutter commands and not the dart commands. What you should do is change the system environment variables (type env in the windows search bar) and add the dart sdk inside the PATH variable. The dart sdk is usually found inside /bin/cache/dart/bin. This worked for me, so give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the flutter\bin sdk path and also the windows\system32 path to the user variables and/or system variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is how I resolved it.

Download and extract dart sdk (I used the stable release)
https://v1-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/install/archive

add the dart sdk bin folder to your path

after you have added it to your path run

> flutter pub global activate webdev

now i can run

> webdev serve

without error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using windows so I used `choco install dart-sdk -<version>` to install dart through the powershell in admin mode. That got rid of my error

Answer (score 0):

Installing flutter is not enough. You need to install the dart sdk.

Pre-req: Make sure you have Chocolatey installed on your machine.

1. Run "choco install dart-sdk" from an elevated prompt.
2. Restart vscode.

That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a more descriptive answer but is similar to the above answers.

Copy the file explorer paths for dart, flutter, and Pub (note the path for dart needs to specify the dart.exe file) and paste them into your user PATH variables (type 'env' in Windows search bar) like the following:

- C:\Users\ [username] \Downloads\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
- C:\Users\ [username] \AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
- C:\Users\ [username] \Downloads\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\packages\flutter

Afterwards save everything and restart your computer before attempting any dart or flutter commands!

[image: dart path]

Answer (score 0):

Just add your flutter path to your env paths, it is often **`C:\src\flutter\bin`**.

This will automatically gives you ability to use **dart** syntax in your terminal etc.

Answer (score 0):

At first find dart.exe directory in your flutter SDK path, properly it's something like this **C:\Users\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin**, then search edit the system environment variables and select environment variables button, from the bottom box as show system variables, select Path and add the mentioned path, then restart your IDE

Answer (score -1):

I went to the dart website and searched for the dart sdk. 
i then chose the option to install dart using setup wizard.
After running the executable file on my laptop it took some time to download all the files but once the setup was complete the error no longer occurred and i was able to run the code successfully.
[Downloading dart setup from dart website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqmkE.png)

[Installing using setup wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHBpC.png)