# Trying to run my flutter application in vscode then get this error: /bin/sh: dart: command not found

Tags: flutter, dart, sh

I'm following along this firebase for flutter tutorial and when I try to run the app I get:/bin/sh: dart: command not found. Here is the image of the error in the output: [image: printed error] Also if I try to run flutter run in my terminal while I'm in the folder baby_names I get an error that says: Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11. I don't if those two are tied into each other.  Here a picture of my user settings : [image: usersettings]

Comment: try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828255/visual-studio-code-dart-not-found

Comment: @Asmoun I added my flutter path to user settings and I'm still getting the same error. I will update my question and show you a picture of my user settings

Comment: ok i updated it @Asmoun

Comment: soo I had to restart vscode over again and know I'm not getting that error anymore thank you! However, now I'm getting a different error that says "could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11." I will make new question for that.