# How can I fix 'CocoaPods 1.8.4 out of date' warning when running Flutter doctor on VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-extensions

I've recently started creating an app by Flutter. Hope if anyone help me with my beginner question:

I installed the Flutter add-on to VS code following [this introductory video](https://youtu.be/8sAyPDLorek), but I got a following warn when I run `>Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor` from the command pallet.

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    ! CocoaPods 1.8.4 out of date (1.11.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
```

How can I fix this warning?

When I check the cocoapods' version on VS Code terminal, it returns `1.12.1`, not `1.8.4`.

VS Code terminal

```
~%gem list pod 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cocoapods (1.12.1)
cocoapods-core (1.12.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (1.6.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
```

Also, I noticed that VS Code's terminal refers to a different path from what Mac OS refers to.

VS Code terminal

```
~%which dart
/Users/{username}/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin//dart
```

Mac OS terminal

```
~%which dart
/Users/{username}/development/flutter/bin/dart
```

As `flutter doctor` on Mac OS successes, the culprit might be this wrong PATH. (but, how does VS Code overwrite PATH? How can I fix it?)

By the way, on Mac OS terminal, flutter doctor successed, so I believe the latest cocoapods version itself has been downloaded. I get this problem only when I run `Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor` on command pallet.

```
~%flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale
    en)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VSCode, open JSON settings (`Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`) from the command palete Cmd+Shift+P. Try to add/edit this line:

```
"dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/{username}/development/flutter",
```

And restart computer.

Reference: [Visual Studio Code: dart not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828255/visual-studio-code-dart-not-found)