# Why am I getting dart:html not found?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a quiz app and the app is running perfectly but there is this passive error
lib/main.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html';


void main() {
  runApp(QuizApp());
}

List questionBank = [...];

class QuizApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<QuizApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<QuizApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentQuestion = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Quiz App",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black87,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.8),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.8),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "images/quiz_icon_3.png",
                      height: 265,
                    )),
                Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: 1.5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          questionBank[_currentQuestion].questionText,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.5,
                            color: Colors.black87,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => _checkAnswer(true, context),
                      child: Text(
                        "True",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => _checkAnswer(false, context),
                      child: Text(
                        "False",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade700),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        _nextQuestion();
                      }),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade700),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }

  _nextQuestion() {
    if (_currentQuestion == questionBank.length - 1) {
      _currentQuestion = 0;
    } else {
      _currentQuestion++;
    }
  }

  _checkAnswer(bool useChoice, BuildContext context) {
    if (questionBank[_currentQuestion].isTrue = useChoice) {
      var correctBar = SnackBar(content: Text("CORRECT !"));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(correctBar);
    } else {
      var falseBar = SnackBar(content: Text("False !"));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(falseBar);
    }
  }
}

class Questions {
  String questionText;
  bool isTrue;

  Questions(this.questionText, this.isTrue);
}
```

I have tried importing both dart:html and io, each seperate, but nothing
I suspect the error is related to the snackBar function, or the build widget I added.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just curious.
Are you using "dart:html" for something?

I faced similar issues, and just removing

`'import 'dart:html';`

works for me, unless you really need it.

[using import 'dart:html' in flutter - Do I need additional dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901960/using-import-darthtml-in-flutter-do-i-need-additional-dependencies)

Comment: It worked.
No, I wasn't using it for anything specific, I am still learning, and the mentor in the course was using it so I did the same. Thank you.

Comment: You need it only for Flutter Web (or just raw dart web).  If you don't have a DOM (like for mobile or desktop or CLI), you can't use it.